# how to get number of this variable in swift 3?

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, uicollectionview

Hi I'm trying to get the numOfVids in Firebase db so I can return that number in my numberOfItemsInSection. But it returns 0 instead of 6. I know it returns 0 because it's reading the empty variable instead of the one in the observeSingleEvent.

> Is there any way for me to get the modified numOfVids instead of the
>   empty numOfVids?

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    var numOfVids = Int() // 0
    let videosRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users/\(currentUserID)/videos")

    videosRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        //get user value
        numOfVids = Int(snapshot.childrenCount)
        print(numOfVids) //prints 6

    })

    return numOfVids //returns 0
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: **Never ever** put an asynchronous task in a method which is supposed to return something. It won't work. Find another solution. For example use a data source model,  load the data in `viewWillAppear` and reload the collection view in the completion handler of the observing method.

Comment: Exactly, doing this work in the methods of UICollectionViewDataSource is bad approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try :-

```
var numOfVids : Int = 0   
@IBOutlet weak var my_CollectionView: UICollectionView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.my_CollectionView.delegate = self
    self.my_CollectionView.dataSource = self

    loadData { (check) in
        print(check)
    }

}


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

     // Use only when you want to reload your data every time your view is presented.
         /*
     loadData { (check) in
        print(check)
    }
    */
}

func loadData(completionBlock : @escaping ((_ success : Bool?) -> Void)){

    Database.database().reference().child("your_PATH").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(Snap ) in

        // Once you have retrieved your data
        // Update the count on the class local variable --  numOfVids
        // Reload your collectionView as ..

        self.my_CollectionView.reloadData()
        completionBlock(true)

  })

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return numOfVids

  }
```

Answer (score -4):

Try this:

```
let videosRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users/\(currentUserID)/videos")

    videosRef.observeSingleEvent(of: DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        for data in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            if let data = data.value  {

              self.numOfVids = self.numOfVids + 1

            }
        }
        print(numOfVids)
    })
```

And regarding the variable numOfVids:

```
var numOfVids = 0
```

That should work thanks

Comment: it is working with me and I'm using it and passing values between views ...etc

Comment: It is definitely **not** working within `numberOfItemsInSection`

Comment: am I missing something in here ? Do you mean the code is not working or will not work with the question ?

Comment: alright, please write a full answer then , so we all benefit from your knowledge